# OAuth - restrict to specific consumer

Tags: oauth

We are implementing an OAuth server and were wondering -- how can we restrict access to it only for users that try to authenticate from a specific service?

(Example: We are running a platform at www.ourPlatformWithOAuthServer.com. 
Only customers of the external service www.whateverExternalService.com are allowed to get an access token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All OAuth2 scenarios require valid client credentials: client_id is always needed and most scenarios also need a client_secret. An OAuth client has to register to the OAuth provider to get these client credentials. So if you simply do not allow public client registration, you can easily control your valid clients.